# Neo4j Server Mode in Java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, server-mode

I have developed a Java application using Neo4j. Basically the user is able to write a cypher query and obtain some results from the graph database. The problem is that it just can access to the graph database one user at a time. And I need the graph database to be accessed by more users at a time. I am accessing the graph db using embedded mode, via Neo4j API for Java. But I have read that it can be possible to access de graph db by more than one user at a time using Neo4j in Server Mode.

I don't know how to start Neo4j in server mode, using Neo4j API for Java. And then executing the application by more than one user at a time.

Thank you,

Vicente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, you just need to run `neo4j start`.   [See the documentation here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/re01.html) for more details.

If you've installed the windows version, it comes with a handy GUI tool that starts and stops the server for you, without the command line.  If you're on a Mac or on linux, you'll probably want to run `neo4j start` or you'll want to set up an init script to do this for you.

Note that servers work differently than embedded databases; generally your server will run on http://localhost:7474/ and will be accessible via REST services, and not via the regular java API.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. This is an example of how I execute a very simple cypher query using the embedded database: 

'GraphDatabaseService graphDb; graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH); ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb); ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (c) RETURN c"); System.out.println(result.dumpToString());'

Now, I have started the server using the GUI tool (I have installed the windows version). How I query the graph db in my code? How I use the REST services?

thank you again,

Vicente

Comment: I am finally accessing and querying the graph db via REST, with Jersey and I am obtaining Json files with the results, but it is slower than querying it via embedded. My graph has 350.000 nodes and 1.500.000 relationships. I don't know if there is a way for not blocking the db when it is accessed by a user via embedded...

thanks

Comment: Vicente, your original question is answered.  You might consider accepting this, and putting out there a new question so that others can see and help answer.